# gRPC C++ SetSslTargetNameOverride changes authority?

Tags: c++, go, grpc, http2

I am developing simple gRPC client in both C++ and Golang.

There is a DialOption in golang client named WithAuthority which overrides the Authority pseudo header in http2 header.

Is there any dial option in C++ with exactly the same function? I find SetSslTargetNameOverride could do something very similar to the DialOption in golang. However, the document here (https://grpc.github.io/grpc/cpp/classgrpc_1_1_channel_arguments.html#a42313e3360b50c354c68572e7bf5bccb) says that This option should be used with caution in production.

What should I notice if I use it in the product? Or is there any function suitable for a production environment?

Comment: I think this thread might help you
https://www.mail-archive.com/search?l=grpc-io@googlegroups.com&q=subject:%22Re%5C%3A+%5C%5Bgrpc%5C-io%5C%5D+Any+alternative+to+SetSslTargetNameOverride%5C%3F%22&o=newest&f=1

Comment: Thanks @nimdrak ! But I need to change the authority in the header to choose which certificate I want to verify